# Passing a Dictionary Variable to a Custom Module

Tags: python, ansible

I have [a custom module for Ansible written in Python](https://github.com/naftulikay/ansible-role-degoss/pull/36) that I maintain, and I need to be able to pass in all detected Ansible facts as a dictionary into this module.

Currently, I'm attempting to do this like so:

```
- name: run tests
  degoss:
    # ...
    facts: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

My module's argument spec looks like this:

```
AnsibleModule(argument_spec=dict(
  # ...
  facts=dict(required=False, default={}),
), ...)
```

My module documentation also specifies this:

```
DOCUMENTATION="""
# ...
options:
  facts:
    required: false
    default: empty dictionary
    description: A dictionary of Ansible facts.
"""
```

However, as I do input sanitization and validation, I receive a `str` instead of a dictionary:

```
if not isinstance(self.facts, dict):
    self.fail("The 'facts' parameter to this module must be a dictionary, not a {}".format(type(self.facts)))
```

This is thrown at runtime:

```
The 'facts' parameter to this module must be a dictionary, not a <type 'str'>
```

Is there a specific syntax I need to use to pass a value as a dictionary, or do I need to treat dictionary variables as JSON and attempt to deserialize them?

Answer (score 5):

As described [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#type), you can specify what type ansible can expect.

```
AnsibleModule(argument_spec=dict(
  # ...
  facts=dict(required=False, default={}, type=dict),
), ...)
```

Then 'facts' will be a dictionary

Answer (score -2):

This works:

1. Pass ansible_facts piping it to `to_json` filter in your play.

   ```
   - name: run tests   
     degoss:
     # ...
     facts: "{{ ansible_facts | to_json }}"
   ```
2. In your python module decode the json using **either** `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval`

   ```
   import json
   import ast
   ...
   facts = json.loads(module.params.get('facts'))
   facts = ast.literal_eval(module.params.get('facts'))
   ...
   ```

Comment: This is hideous. Why not base64-encode it, just to be sure? @fraff's answer is the solution...